# RemoveFromSuperView don't work

Tags: iphone, xcode4.3

Although I declared the `UIView` in the header file (as below):

```
IBOutlet UIView *aCustomMsgBoxView;
```

The RemoveSuperView works in one method but not in the other. It works if I put it in this method:

```
-(IBAction)showMsgBox:(id)sender

{

vc = [ViewController sharedInstance].self;

aCustomMsgBoxView = [[UIView alloc] init];

NSArray *nibObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"customMsgBox" owner:self options:nil];

aCustomMsgBoxView = [nibObjects objectAtIndex:0];

aCustomMsgBoxView.frame = CGRectMake(35, 80, 250, 146);

[vc.view addSubview:aCustomMsgBoxView];
}
```

But I don't need it in the above method, I need it in the method below where it doesn't work:

```
-(IBAction)hideMsgBox:(id)sender

{

    [newAnnotationTitle resignFirstResponder];

    [aCustomMsgBoxView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Of course both methods sit in the same class...

Why isn't the view being removed from the screen??

Comment: is your [newAnnotationTitle resignFirstResponder]; working ? hav u checked that ?

Comment: You're setting aCustomMsgBoxView twice. Once with an initialiser, and secondly with an object from the nib. And `vc = [ViewController sharedInstance].self;` is giving off a smell.

Comment: would you `NSlog` the value that `aCustomMsgBoxView` has in `hideMsgBox`, just before calling `removeFromSuperview`? Is it nil?

Comment: The NSLog shows (null). Before entering the first question i tried to do the same without the initialization but it was the same… I checked what would the NSLog give me without the initialization and it's also (null).

Comment: And yes, the firstResponder works fine.

Comment: Another interesting fact is that the tag is 0… after i give it 1001 in the first method.

Comment: Ok, I checked the number of subviews under vc.view in the first and second methods. In the first it shows 13, in the second it shows 0… How come?

Comment: Ok, this is solved. First, I had to declare the "vc = [ViewController sharedinstance].self" in both methods. Second, i added a subview in between these two methods which i forgot about so i need to remove the subview before the latest one. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code may be help for remove UIView (aCustomMsgBoxView)

```
  -(IBAction)hideMsgBox:(id)sender

{
    [newAnnotationTitle resignFirstResponder];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25
     animations:^{ self.aCustomMsgBoxView.alpha = 0.0;}
     completion:^(BOOL finished){ [ self.aCustomMsgBoxView removeFromSuperview]; }];

}
```

Thanks :)